# ActiveMQ Stomp python client NACK consumes message

Tags: python, activemq-classic, stomp

I'm using ActiveMQ classic v5.16.3 and experimenting with NACK. My expectation is that if the client sends a NACK then the message will remain on the queue and be available for another client. My code is below. I set a prefetch of 1, and ack mode of client-individual.

If I omit the conn.nack() call then I see my print statements, and the message remains on the queue - hence I believe that ActiveMQ is looking for an ACK or NACK.

When I include the conn.nack() call then I again see my print statements, and the message is removed from the queue.

Is this expected behaviour? I think a client should be able to reject malformed messages by NACK-ing and that eventually ActiveMQ should put them to a dead letter queue.

```
import time
import sys   
import stomp

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):
    def on_error(self, frame):
        print('received an error "%s"' % frame.body)

    def on_message(self, frame):
        # experiment with and without the following line
        conn.nack(id=frame.headers['message-id'], subscription=frame.headers["subscription"])
        print('received a message "%s"' % frame.body)
        print('headers  "%s"' % frame.headers)
        

print('Connecting ...')
conn = stomp.Connection()
conn.set_listener('', MyListener())
conn.connect('admin', 'admin', wait=True)
print('Connected')
conn.subscribe(destination='/queue/audit', id=1, ack='client-individual', headers={'activemq.prefetchSize': 1})
```

Comment: What is the broker configuration?  Do you have the broker configured for server side redelivery?

Comment: @TimBish - I did not, I now do and I see expected behaviour. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Tim Bish, I needed to configure ActiveMQ to retry. I made the following changes to activemq.xml

Added scheduler support to the broker:

```
<broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
   brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}"
   schedulerSupport="true" >
```

Specified the redelivery plugin:

```
<plugins>
        <redeliveryPlugin fallbackToDeadLetter="true"
                          sendToDlqIfMaxRetriesExceeded="true">
            <redeliveryPolicyMap>
                <redeliveryPolicyMap>
                    <defaultEntry>
                        <redeliveryPolicy maximumRedeliveries="4"
                                          initialRedeliveryDelay="5000"
                                          redeliveryDelay="10000"/>
                    </defaultEntry>
                </redeliveryPolicyMap>
            </redeliveryPolicyMap>
        </redeliveryPlugin>
    </plugins>
```

And then for my chosen destination, specify that poison messages be sent to a specific queue - default is to publish to a Topic.

```
    <destinationPolicy>
        <policyMap>
          <policyEntries>
            <policyEntry queue="audit" prioritizedMessages="true" >
              <deadLetterStrategy>
                <individualDeadLetterStrategy queuePrefix="DLQ."
                      useQueueForQueueMessages="true"/>
              </deadLetterStrategy>
            </policyEntry>
```